# Spring 3 validation: using messages.property entry inside errorArgs?

Tags: java, spring, localization, validation, locale

what I'm looking for is very easy to explain:
I have a form which must support both italian and english. Let's suppose I have a First Name input text field. The form label will be:

- for EN: "First Name"
- for IT: "Nome"

what I want is a validation error message like these

- for EN: "the **First Name** field is required"
- for IT: "il campo **Nome** è richiesto"

please note I'm quoting the *field name* inside the error message.

I have the `messages_en.properties` with the lines:

```
errors.empty.field = the {0} field is required
registration.form.firstname = First Name
```

and of course the `messages_it.properties` with the lines:

```
errors.empty.field = il campo {0} è richiesto
registration.form.firstname = Nome
```

Now, inside my custom validator class I have

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "firstname", "errors.empty.field", new Object[]{"registration.form.firstname"}, "the First Name is required");
```

which doesn't works properly. The output is the "registration.form.username" string as it is. I'd like to inject the field name with the proper locale at runtime. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: sorry i wanted to delete my stupid question..but i miss the track of your question..could you delete your comment..

Comment: actually i asked this question at time when i do not know what message Source is..

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach, there should be better one's out there though:

Inject the `messageSource` into the Controller or the validator:

```
@Autowired MessageSource messageSource
```

In your controllers `@RequestMapping` method, take in Locale as a parameter, Spring will populate it for you.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String myMethod(..., Locale locale){
   ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "firstname", "errors.empty.field", new Object[]{messageSource.getMessage("registration.form.firstname", new Object[]{}, locale)}, "the First Name is required");
....
}
```

**Update:**

You can get a handle on `Locale` in Validator using [LocaleContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html)

Comment: there's thing I don't get. My CustomValidator class implements Validator form org.springframework.validation.Validator. CustomValidator must define a validate(Object target, Errors errors) which doesn't allow a Locale parameter. how can I pass the locale object to validator?

Comment: I have added an update, you can use `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` static call. It does feel a little round about, would recommend waiting for more answers to come in, there has to be a simpler way to do this.